# How redraw on canvas resize without blurring?

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas

When the canvas element is resized (via the style changing) I also want to scale the canvas' drawn image as well. I cannot just change the height/width as this causes the canvas to clear itself, so I do:

1. Create a temporary canvas element
2. Draw the current canvas' image onto that temporary canvas
3. Resize the current canvas
4. Draw the temp canvas' image back to the current canvas but scaled to the new size

This results in some blurring - very noticeable after many resizes (example: when dragging to resize). How would I do this without any blurring?

**EDIT:** Turning off image smoothing (`context.webkitImageSmoothingEnabled = false;`) does *not* fix the problem, it simply makes it redraw it more and more jagged until the image looks nothing like the original after a number of resizes.

**Called on resize event:**

```
    var tmpCanvas = null;       

    //Make a temporary canvas
    tmpCanvas = document.createElement( "canvas" );

    //Set its size to be equal
    tmpCanvas.height = originalCanvas.height;
    tmpCanvas.width = originalCanvas.width;

    //Draw our current canvas onto it
    tmpCanvas.getContext( "2d" ).drawImage( originalCanvas, 0, 0 );

    //Set new dimensions
    originalCanvas.width = originalCanvas.offsetWidth;
    originalCanvas.height = originalCanvas.offsetHeight;

    var originalContext = originalCanvas.getContext( "2d" );

    //Set background and colors
    originalContext.fillStyle = "#ffffff";
    originalContext.strokeStyle = "#000000";

    //Set paintbrush
    originalContext.lineWidth = 4;
    originalContext.lineCap = "round";

    //Fill background as white
    originalContext.fillRect( 0, 0, originalCanvas.width, originalCanvas.height );

    //We have a saved signature
    if ( SignatureCanvas.hasSignature === true )
    {
        //Draw it back but scaled (results in blurred image)
        originalContext.drawImage( tmpCanvas, 0, 0, tmpCanvas.width, tmpCanvas.height, 0, 0, originalCanvas.width, originalCanvas.height );

        /** 
         * This results in a blurred image as well
         //Draw it back but scaled
         originalContext.scale( originalCanvas.width / tmpCanvas.width, originalCanvas.height / tmpCanvas.height );
         originalContext.drawImage( tmpCanvas, 0, 0, tmpCanvas.width, tmpCanvas.height, 0, 0, tmpCanvas.width, tmpCanvas.height );
         */
    }
```

Is there a way to get the strokes and "scale" all those points and redraw?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of taking the rendered image from the original canvas, actually redraw the image. By that, I mean execute the same logic you executed against the original canvas, but with the points involved scaled to the new size.

If you can, think about using SVG instead. It scales well by its nature.

Edit: Another option I've thought of is to simply use a gigantic canvas to start with. Sizing down tends to look better than sizing up, especially with smoothing on.

Comment: How would I do that? The image drawn on the first canvas is done by the user, so I have no knowledge of what it will be beforehand. Is there a way to grab the information from a drawn-on canvas and scale those points and redraw them?

Comment: You would need to store the commands the user executed (I guess which points were drawn on) and replay that logic at the new size. You need some kind of vector representation to resize cleanly. Otherwise, you're just resizing a raster image which is just going to look off resized. Canvas is just a canvas; it doesn't store layers or components like an SVG does.

Answer (score -2):

*Edit II: The original answer was irrelevant, though the comment I had made is relevant, and am now promoting it and editing it to be an answer...and the answer I had given was not all that great anyway* **.

*Of course* if you scale up raster graphics, that is, from an image with a smaller pixel dimensions of pixels, create an image with higher pixel dimensions, you are going to get blurred images. By scaling up, you're making a low resolution picture high resolution, but *without the high resolution details*.

There's absolutely no way around that blurriness unless you make multiple additional assumptions about your raster image like the only gray you'd see is at an image edge, or corners can only occur at apparent inflection points where the angle between the tangents of the joined curves must be 100 degrees or less.  Essentially, you'd have to give additional information so that your higher resolution image can have detail "filled in".  It's not all that terribly different from reverse engineering an SVG from a raster.

So, you appear to want to emulate is scaling *vector graphics*, in which the only solution is to save the commands, draw a SVG, or draw to a bigger canvas like Stuart Branham suggested.

** I had originally proposed that invoking `drawImage` would distort the pixels *even if it were not scaled*, and that it would be better to work with the actual pixel data.  *If that's true, I can't find proof*, but that's irrelevant, as he wanted his image scaled up, *without blurring*...which is impossible, as I just mentioned.

Comment: Using the data from `getImageData` is far from simple. All that returns you is an array of all the pixels' red, green, blue and alpha values. How would I scale that?

Comment: I'm sorry, it wasn't clear to me that you were scaling.  Well, *of course* if you scale raster graphics, you are going to get blurred images.  There's absolutely no way around that unless you make multiple additional assumptions about your rastered image (like the only gray you'd see is at an image edge, what constitutes a corner, etc).  What you appear to want to emulate is scaling *vector graphics*, in which the *only* solution is to save the commands or use SVG like Stuart Branham suggested.

Comment: You are incorrect that it is impossible. As long as you know the paths created, you can scale those and redraw them on the newly sized canvas. This will produce a non-blurry, scaled copy. See here for more: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19284983/857025

Comment: From a raster image! If you are using the paths created, you ARE NOT using a raster image, now, are you?

Comment: A raster image is pixels, and only pixels.  If you are using the paths, you are essentially using vector graphics.

Comment: correct. I guess there are limitations on what you can redraw reliably.

Comment: I think this answer is missing the distinction between *blurring* and *pixelation*

Comment: Suppose you want to create a high resolution raster image from a low resolution raster image without any additional assumptions about the image. Either one of two things can happen: you use a nearest neighbor algorithm to pick the color of the pixels, resulting in pixelation, or you use bilinear interpolation or digital filtering (which will result in blurriness).  As of 2013-11-28, there appears to be no way to convince the HTML5 Canvas 2d APIs to use a nearest neighbor method. So, if you scale an image up, *it's going to be blurry*. This doesn't seem to me like a hard concept to grasp.