# How scale all the points used to make lines/curves on a canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am recording all the points drawn on a canvas via the `mousedown` and `mousemove` events. When the canvas is resized (for example, if it was 100w x 200h, and the user makes it 200w x 400h) I want to redraw all those points/lines but at the new scale. What's the proper way to do this?

I am currently using code like below but it does not draw properly. It draws weird extra lines.

To save the points, I record the point in `mousedown` and `mousemove` and mark a line as done in `mouseup`.

**Called on resize event:**

```
//The new ratios
var wRatio = canvas.width / oldWidth;
var hRatio = canvas.height / oldHeight;

//We need to scale and draw all our points
for ( var i = 0, last = savedPoints.length - 1; i < last; i++ ) {
    var start = savedPoints[ i ];
    var end = savedPoints[ i + 1 ];

    //We're at a new line
    if ( start === "stopline" ) continue;

    //We're finishing a previous line
    else if ( end === "stopline" ) {
        i++;
        continue;
    }

    //Resize them
    start.x = start.x * wRatio;
    start.y = start.y * hRatio;
    end.x = end.x * wRatio;
    end.y = end.y * hRatio;

    //These lines don't make a difference
    //savedPoints[ i ] = start;
    //savedPoints[ i + 1 ] = end;

    //Start recording
    context.beginPath();

    //Move the "pen" to the point
    context.moveTo( start.x, start.y );

    //Make the connection of the "line" with our data (I draw the lines originally this way to make more "natural")
    context.quadraticCurveTo( start.x, start.y, end.x, end.y );

    //This doesn't work either
    //context.lineTo( start.x, start.y, end.x, end.y );

    //Draw the line
    context.stroke();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is you are applying the ratio twice to each point by modifying `savedPoints[i]` AND `savedPoints[i+1]` through the `start` and `end` objects. The next iteration, where `i = i+1`, `savedPoints[i]` will have already been modified once.

```
    //The new ratios
    var wRatio = canvas.width / oldWidth;
    var hRatio = canvas.height / oldHeight;

    //We need to scale and draw all our points
    for ( var i = 0, last = savedPoints.length - 1; i < last; i++ ) {
        var start = savedPoints[ i ];
        var end = savedPoints[ i + 1 ];
        var endx, endy, startx, starty;

        //We're at a new line
        if ( start === "stopline" ) continue;

        //We're finishing a previous line
        else if ( end === "stopline" ) {
            i++;
            continue;
        }

        //Resize them
        startx = start.x * wRatio;
        starty = start.y * hRatio;
        endx = end.x * wRatio;
        endy = end.y * hRatio;

        //Start recording
        context.beginPath();

        //Move the "pen" to the point
        context.moveTo( startx, starty );

        //Make the connection of the "line" with our data (I draw the lines originally this way to make more "natural")
        context.quadraticCurveTo( startx, starty, endx, endy );

        //This doesn't work either
        //context.lineTo( startx, starty, end.x, end.y );

        //Draw the line
        context.stroke();
    }

    for ( var i = 0, last = savedPoints.length - 1; i < last; i++ ) {
        if (savedPoints[i] !== 'stopline') {
            savedPoints[i].x *= wRatio;
            savedPoints[i].y *= hRatio;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, that solves the mis-drawing problem! But now I see that the image is not resizing. All I've done is change the x/y, but not the distance between them (so if I draw an X, it always remains the same size). Do you know how to calculate that?

Comment: Can you edit your answer a little so I can mark it as the answer? All it needs is this: within the loop, change to `startX = start.x * wRatio` and the same for startY (like you did for endX/endY) and then put a loop at the end to save the ratios back to the `savedPoints` array. (I've found that it only works if the ratios are saved after the first loop is done)

Comment: Added the changes you asked for. It's untested but I believe it will work right.

Comment: Thanks, there's just two small errors. Your `context.moveTo( start.x, start.y );` and `context.quadraticCurveTo( start.x, start.y, endx, endy );` are using `start.x` and `start.y` not the `startX` and `startY` local variables. Could you please change those?